# How can I make a group of <td>s linkable in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to add a link to a whole row except one td. I managed to make the whole row clickable by the following

```
<tbody>
    <% @inbox_messages.each do |message| %>
        <tr data-link="<%= show_received_message_path(message) %>">
            <td>
                <%= check_box_tag 'select' %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= message.received_sender %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= message.subject %>
            </td>           
            <td>
                <%= message.created_at %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

and using the following coffeescript

```
$ ->
    $("tr[data-link]").click ->
        window.location = $(this).data("link")
```

However the problem with this is that when I tick the checkbox it redirects me to the `show_received_message_path` which I do not want.

I've tried messing around with divs however I've learnt that its not valid html to put divs inside of trs.

Is there any way to link all of a row except the checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way around your problem would be to attach click handlers to the `<td>`s instead of the `<tr>`s and then use jQuery's [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), and [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selectors to exclude the cells which contain checkboxes. Something like this:

```
$('tr[data-link] td:not(:has(:checkbox))').click ->
    $tr = $(@).closest('tr')
    #...
```

Also note the use of [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) in the click handler, we use that because `@` will be the `<td>` and `data-link` is on the `<tr>`; you could use [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) instead of `closest` if you want, `closest` just makes things clearer to me.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/qH282/